# How to change element's Opacity / Transparency and keep body background-image still visible?

Tags: html, css

I m new at coding and first question to ask here.

This is first time that I was unable to find an answer online, maybe because I am unable to explain/describe it well. But here I am able to post a picture.

[Exactly what I want do make. This dark shade background of an element but to keep body background still visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8HmV.png)

Can you please help me how can I do this in CSS?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your non-off-putting comment. Reason is given in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set background for the element:
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
Pay attention at 0.5. It run from 0 to 1. More high more dark.

Comment: Yup. Thx! I was always using HEX, I see now RGB has advantages too.

Answer (score 2):

- create a div with position absolute
- set it's background-color as black
- set it's opacity as 0.5(adjust **opacity** as you required,which **determine** your **transparency** level).

```css
html{
      width:100%,height:100%;
      }
    body{ 
      background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg);
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      background-size:cover;
      }
#black-box{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:50%;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  height:50%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="black-box"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a div for the background image, which I have added, you then need another div in order to vertical align the content, similar to your example and finally a third div that will hold the content.

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
   <div class="background-module">
      <div class="background-info">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris non imperdiet enim. Aenean eget dolor in risus aliquam pellentesque. Ut porta nec ex vel tincidunt. Maecenas varius accumsan posuere. Donec non blandit ipsum. Duis vel eros nunc. Donec aliquam ac ipsum et ultrices.</p>
          <form>
            <input type="email" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
  background:url("https://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/sierra-2.jpg?quality=82&strip=all") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height:800px; /* this can be anything */
  display:table; /* required to vertically align the content */
  width:100%;
}

.background-module {
  display:table-cell; /* required to vertically align the content */
  vertical-align:middle; /* required to vertically align the content */
}

.background-info {
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* required to create the opacity look in your example */
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is a link to a working fiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/czy5ycsr/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNPyKR)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content</p>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:1400px;
  background: white url(http://lorempixel.com/1400/1200/nature/1/) no-repeat center;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin : 20px auto;
}
.content {
  display:block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background:transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.overlay {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```